# What is the use of this parameter In java

Tags: java

In java we can call a global variable in parameter like

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

My question is that this method required int on parameter but we give a global variable here Why and what its call.

Comment: Open the source code of `JFrame` and see what is the value of  `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`

Comment: In modern code (Java 5 and above) the type of the parameter could be an `enum` (e.g. `CloseOperation`) instead of `int`, which would make the API much clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Very simply you don't want to be using magic numbers so constants are provided.

Answer (score 0):

`JFrame` is a class, that apparently contains a *static* field. If the docs tell you it's of type `int`, it is. And it can be called this way because it's static, which means that you don't need an instance of class `JFrame` to access those fields - they are statically stored in the memory.

Answer (score 0):

[`JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#EXIT_ON_CLOSE) is called a *constant* (or a *static* variable).  This lets you access its value from anywhere.  Not just as a parameter to a function, `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` is a value you can use anywhere.

[`setDefaultCloseOperation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation(int)) takes an `int` as its parameter to tell it what close operation you want.  [`EXIT_ON_CLOSE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) - which happens to be 3, but could change - is the operation you are telling it to do.